# Click event only working on first page of table Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, dom, angular8

I have used Angular Material to create a simple table. On one column I have implemented simple click event. Also, the table has pagination so it shows 10 records per page. On first page my click event works normally but on other pages it does not work. How can I implement it?

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="changes">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Changes </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let i=index">
                <button  (click)="change(element)"></button>            
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

TS CODE

```
change(element){
    this.input=[];
    this.changing=true;
    const elementIndex = this.details.findIndex((elem: any) => element === elem);
    this.isChanged[elementIndex] = true;
  }
```

I read about event delegation in JQuery. How can I implement somthing similar to implement click function on elements which are not currently in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

When it happened to me, I found the data in the underlying database was complete for only the first page and as it was incomplete for the rest of the data the query was returning an empty object.